# What are the complications with infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces which are not suitable for $T=\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_jP_j$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, projection

$T=\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_jP_j$ would not be suitable for immediate generalization to  infinite dimensional Hilbert Space s $\mathcal H$ Since in that case spectra of bounded self  adjoint linear operator may be more *complicated*.

My Question is  **What are the complications with infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces which are not  suitable  for $T=\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_jP_j$?**.In simple words,What are the properties infinite dimensional Hilbert Spaces that will not be compatible with using $T=\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_jP_j$

Reference:[Page 493-494](https://docs.ufpr.br/%7Eeidam/2019/2/CM075/Kreyszig.pdf)

Comment: The spectra can be more complicated because they can be infinite. That is the issue.

Comment: @JPMcCarthy:"Complicated" in what  sense?What specific property gets disobeyed by $T$ if we take  infinite dimension Hilbert space into consideration that is,followed by T if $\mathcal H$ is finite dimensional and disobeyed if  $\mathcal H$ is infinite dimensional?

Comment: I just told you. You can have infinite spectra and so that finite expression doesn't work. Complicated here refers to infinite.

Comment: Moreover, the spectra might not be even countable (though it has to be compact for a bounded $T$). The right substitute then for the finite sum is an integral.